Trouble getting Auto-reply to run
I have been having horrendous trouble getting Auto GPT to run. I have tried three different versions. Auto GPT 0.5.0, 0.4.7, and the so-called stable version 0.2.2.
The strangest thing happens when I try to run 0.5.0 the latest version, and that is after installing it from GitHub and installing all the requirements, when I try to run it it starts and then completely deletes the entire installation directory where I put the files all 98 MB of it or so.
I've cloned Auto GPT 0.2.2 from GitHub and when I try to install the requirements for that I run into library problems because some of the libraries are old and not available through pip anymore.
With version 0.4.7, it starts to run gets through the first phase of the steps then crashes on some kind of json error with the reply from openai. I've looked into this error more and other people seem to have had this error from this particular version of as well.
I'm running all of this on a Windows 10 machine in Debian WSL in a Python venv. I've been using the standard git clone commands and python pip to do the installation work. I've been wondering if anybody has gotten version 0.5.0  or any other version recently to run on their Windows machine and if so how did they do it?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
